# Error When Parse Api Connects

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I am using the precustomised login and signup window in Parse and I have found that when I run the app first time with the contents and settings reset it works but then the second go (without resetting contents and setting) it fails giving me a Login Error and NSURLErrorDomain error - 1011 And I have tested it and to get it working I need to reset the contents and settings. But how do I solve this issue, my [xcode-project](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/c2fr59mztdpyb3t/AAAT5pbxgX3ii-bTMhkALhtKa?dl=0) and my [charles-proxy](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bqq9oswrq7kdkbo/sitelog.chls?dl=0) this is for the relationship between Parse and the app using http proxy.

I am using iOS, Swift - Xcode 6.3.1

Comment: The [Screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/poqrq3092d3id71/iOS%20Simulator%20Screen%20Shot%2017%20May%202015%2012.52.34.png?dl=0) Of The error

Comment: Please post the part of the code that does the logIn.

Answer (score 0):

Forgot to add the logout button, so when the app launches it was trying to log someone in but there was already someone logged in. And the whole resetting contents thing was for resetting the app so the person would have been logged out!

Thanks Everyone